# Python unittest module diff consider `tzinfo=<UTC>` and `tzinfo=tzutc()` unequal

Tags: python, testing, python-unittest

I have a problem using `assertListEqual()` in Python's `unittest` module.

When I do `self.assertListEqual(expected, result)` it compares items correctly. But when there is a little difference, then I get a diff. And in that diff, besides items which definitely differ, I get many lines like:

[image]

The question is: How could I get rid of that, to see only elements, which realy differ?

To generate `expected` timestamp i use `dateutil.parser.parse` and Django's ORM.

Here's the sample code which shows that:

```
from datetime import datetime
import unittest
import pytz

from dateutil.parser import parse


class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_foo(self):

        expected = [{
            'value': 1,
            'timestamp': datetime(2018, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=pytz.utc),
        }]

        result = [{
            'value': 0,
            'timestamp': parse('2018-01-01T00:00:00Z'),
        }]

        self.assertListEqual(expected, result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Please post a copy of the code.

Comment: @glenfant Could you look again? I updated the description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
from datetime import datetime
import unittest
import pytz

import dateutil
from dateutil.parser import parse


class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_foo(self):

        expected = [{
            'value': 1,
            'timestamp': datetime(2018, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=dateutil.tz.tz.tzutc()),
        }]

        result = [{
            'value': 1,
            'timestamp': parse('2018-01-01T00:00:00Z'),
        }]

        self.assertListEqual(expected, result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: The solution works, but in the original code I am using Django ORM to get one of the lists, so my only option is to replace parse's UTC object or UTC object returned by ORM to match?

Comment: It seems that dateutils does not rely on pytz as timezones database and has its own. That's why you have this difference. I'm not a Django expert. Try to find what Django uses to parse serialized datetimes with timezones.